# How to don't validate form with Ajax buttons

Tags: forms, validation, wicket, onsubmit

I have a problem with validation on form actually sub-form.

In my website I have some kind of table and "Add row" button (BlockingAjaxSubmitLink).
When I try add let say 2 rows, I get validation error (because row in this table has Required=True parameter) and I can't add another row. I tried use simple AjaxLink but it doesn't have reference to form in onClick method and when I complete some rows and click "Add row" this data get lost.

I want to enable validation only after "save" button click.

Any idea how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I do something like you want using an `AjaxLink`. 
My `AjaxLink`:

```
   private AjaxLink addNewRow = new AjaxLink("addNewRow") {
      @Override
      public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
         MyEntityObject newTableRowObject = new MyEntityObject(irrelevantParameter);
         entityObjectTableService.createNewRowInDB(newTableRowObject );
         target.add(listViewContainer);
      }
   };
```

In this code the `listViewContainer` is a `WebMarkupContainer` which contains a `ListView` holding the table rows.

When i click this `AjaxLink` a new object representing a row in my table is added to the database and then the container containing the `ListView` is being refreshed refreshing the `ListView` and the new empty object is being fetched from the DB and shown as a new row in my table at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your structure maybe you are looking after disabling validation using `setDefaultFormProcessing(true);` - http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractSubmitLink.html#setDefaultFormProcessing%28boolean%29

Comment: I set this paramter, validation was disabled but table (form) was acting little strange. When I have couple of rows with data and I add another one suddenly all rows become empty.

I couldn't update form without validation. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

For now I write some kind of hack

First I set

```
addKnowledgeLink.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
```

and next

```
    BlockingAjaxSubmitLink<Object> addKnowledgeLink = new BlockingAjaxSubmitLink<Object>(
                "link_knowledge_add") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        ChangeDataForm.this.process(this);

        /*  some code   */


        target.add(form.get(MY_CONTAINER_ID));
    }
(...)
```

and my hack...

```
//HACK
public void process(IFormSubmitter object){
    if (!isEnabledInHierarchy() || !isVisibleInHierarchy())
    {
        return;
    }
    // run validation
    validate();
        /*if (hasError())
    {
        // mark all children as invalid
        markFormComponentsInvalid();
            // let subclass handle error
        callOnError(object);
    }
    else
    {*/
        // mark all children as valid
        markFormComponentsValid();
            // before updating, call the interception method for clients
        beforeUpdateFormComponentModels();
            // Update model using form data
        updateFormComponentModels();
            // validate model objects after input values have been bound
        onValidateModelObjects();
        if (hasError())
        {
            callOnError(object);
            return;
        }
        // Form has no error
        delegateSubmit(object);
    //}
}
```

and I ovveride one method

```
@Override
    protected void onError(){
        super.onError();
        this.updateFormComponentModels();
    }
```

I know it is ugly solution but I couldn't  figure out anything better..
And I couldn't shutdown feedback messages