# How to set up a Form with master and detail in Wicket

Tags: jquery, wicket, master-detail

I work on an Wicket application in which users can, in a page, type a message and add multiple links to that message. The page design is so that a user can type a message and add a link at the same time, and then submit everything with one click.

I have created separate domain objects for Message and Link, where a Message has a collection (Set) of Links as a data member. Below is the part of the HTML that we need to use to store message and links.

```
 <section wicket:id="newMessageSection" class="new-message">

     <div wicket:id="messageEditor" class="message-editor" style="">
           <form wicket:id="newMessageForm" class="write-new-message">                    
               <span wicket:id="feedback" ></span>
               <input wicket:id="title" class="new-message-title" type="text" required="required" placeholder="Title of the message" />
               <span wicket:id="titleFeedback" ></span>

               <div class="editor-container">
                    <textarea wicket:id="text" style="width:583px; height:120px; float:left;" cols="60" rows="5" id="txtEditor">
                              Some Initial Content here
                    </textarea> 
               </div>
               <span wicket:id="textFeedback" ></span>

               <a class="add-links">Add Links</a>

               <div class="link-sets">                               
                   <div class="link-set" style="display:none">
                        <input name="link-name-0" type="text" class="link-label" placeholder="Label"/>
                        <input name="link-url-0" type="url" class="link-url" placeholder="http://"/> 
                        <a class="extra-link">+</a> 
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <footer class="new-message-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Message" class="blue submit-new-message" />
                </footer>
           </form>                        
    </div>

</section>
```

Note: the "extra-link" class triggers some jquery code that adds new links:

```
$(".link-sets").delegate(".extra-link", "click", function() {
var linkCount = $('.link-set').length;
$('.link-sets').append('<div class="link-set added-set"><input name="link-name-' + linkCount + '" type="text" class="link-label" placeholder="Label"/><input name="link-url-' + linkCount + '"type="url" class="link-url" placeholder="http://"/><a class="extra-link">+</a></div>');
});
```

What is the best practice for doing display and, more important, save of such master-detail situations in Wicket?

Thanks in advance,

Henk

Comment: I do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17776437/534877 . Maybe this will help you a bit.

Comment: The problem is we have to use existing HTML/JS/CSS. So I am not sure whether this is going to work integrating with the solution mentioned in the link above.

Comment: So show some code to help you

Comment: Added some code, see above.